# I want to delete file from server using http doDelete() method

Tags: java, servlets

if i want to delete welcome.html file how to delete it using http doDelete() methode how to do it i am new to java so plz help me

```
public void doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  boolean success = false;
  File file = null;
  try {
    file = searchFile(request);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Request.class.getName()).
       log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  if (!file.exists()) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); 
    return;
  } else {
    success = file.delete(); // actual delete operation
  }
  if (success) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
  }
}

private  String searchFile(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
  String fileName = req.getPathInfo();
  fileName = fileName.substring(1);
  return fileName;
}
```

Comment: doesn't this work? How?

Comment: Is the file part of the .war file?

Comment: Does your code work? If not, how does it fail? Does the user under which the servlet container runs have permission to delete the file in question?

Comment: my searchFile method returns String and in doDelete it wont take as String and if i declare a variable file type i.e. File file=null it gives me error.....is there any other method than this??

Answer (score 5):

While we wait for you to explain *how* your code "doesn't work" ... I should point out that if this code *did* work, it would be **extremely dangerous**.

Your code makes no attempt to check that the user (i.e. the guy sending the request) *should* be allowed to delete the file, or what the user is attempting to delete.  If some bad guy sent you a DELETE request with ".."'s in it, they could probably trick your web server into attempting to delete **any file in the file system!!!**  (Hopefully you never run your web servers as "root" ...)

---

UPDATE: The answer to your Question is simple.  Change

```
file = searchFile(request);
```

to

```
file = new File(searchFile(request));
```

But that is the *least* of your problems!

Comment: My serachFile method returns String while in doDelete method it wont take as string .when i declere the varible file i.e File file=null then on file = searchFile(request); line it gives me error incompatible type

Comment: as u said If some bad guy sent you a DELETE request with ".."'s in it, they could probably trick your web server into attempting to delete any file in the file system!!! how to prevent this ???

Comment: The simple way is to test the URL to see if it contains any ".." path components and reject the request if it does.  But my real point is that **YOU** should be thinking of this kind of thing when you design a web service.

Comment: Agreed. Validate the sanity of the input AND validate the source that sends the request. Applying user authentication to begin with.